# c# Regular expression for words in brackets with separator

Tags: c#, regex

I need to parse a text and check if between all squared brackets is a `-` and before and after the `-` must be at least one character. 
I tried the following code, but it doesn't work. The matchcount is to large.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[\.*-.*]");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(textBox.Text);
```

SampleText:

```
Node
  (Entity [1-5])
```

Comment: A couple of points. 1) `*` matches 0 or more occurences. You want + probably. 2) square brackets are special characters and will need to be escaped. They are used to define sets of characters. 3) You will probably want non-greedy matching by putting a ? after your + to tell it to match minimum number of characters rather than as many as possible.

Comment: @Chris Agreed on points 1 & 2, but non-greedy matching shouldn't be necessary to fulfill his requirements.

Comment: @ean5533: You're right. I was thinking about strings like `[asdasd-][asdasda]` but you are right that non-greedy won't help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets mean something special in Regexes, you'll need to escape them. Additionally, if you want **at least one** character then you need to use `+` rather than `*`.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[.+-.+\]");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(textBox.Text);
```

Comment: With this expression i always get zero results.

Comment: @Tomtom I just noticed that you had escaped one of the `.` characters (I copy-pasted without noticing). That was causing the problem. Try it now.

Comment: This will match `"[test-][-foo]"` which I suspect isn't desired.

Comment: @Chris True. Your answer is more robust if that use case is a requirement. You should mention that case in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Figured I might as well provide an answer... To reiterate my points (with modifications):

1. `*` matches 0 or more occurences. You want + probably.
2. square brackets are special characters and will need to be escaped. They are used to define sets of characters.
3. You will probably want to exclude `[` and `]` from your "any character" matching

Put this all together and the following should do you better:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[[^-[\]]+-[^[\]]+\]");
```

Although its a little messy the key thing is that `[^[\]]` means any character except a square bracket. `[^-[\]]` means that but also disallows `-`. This is an optimisation and not required but it just reduces the work the regular expression engine has to do when working out the match. Thanks to ridgerunner for pointing out this optimisation.

Comment: +1. But I would throw a dash into that first negative char class to eliminate some extra backtracking finding the dash.

Comment: @ridgerunner: Edited my answer accordingly. I have to admit to being a bit vague on why you do that because although I udnerstand how that would work I'm not that good on the details of how regular expression matching works so didn't want to try to go itno detail of why it is an optimisation when I'd probably get it wrong. :)

Comment: Chapter 6: _Crafting an Efficient Expression_ of [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "By Jeffrey Friedl. Best book on Regex - ever!") ends with a section titled: _"The Freeflowing Regex"_. It culminates with the take home message: _"A Well-Guided Regex is a Fast Regex"_. This book (entertainingly) teaches one how to _think in regex_, i.e. in terms of the how the underlying NFA engine must perform its job. If you use regex a lot, the time spent reading this book will pay for itself _many_ times over.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string txt = "(Entity [1-5])";
 Regex reg = new Regex(@"\[.+\-.+\]");
```

if it is for #:

```
 string txt = "(Entity [1-5])";
 Regex reg = new Regex(@"\[\d+\-\d+\]");
```

Comment: This will match `"[test-][-foo]"` which I suspect isn't desired.